# Jquery Hover animate issue

Tags: jquery, hover

I am using jquery to create a hover effect on my nav menu. My jquery is as follows:

```
$(".hoverMenu").css({"opacity":"0"});

        $("#menu-nav li:nth-child(2) a").hover(function(){
            $(".hoverMenu").stop().show().animate({
                top: '88',
                opacity: '1'
            }, 500);
        }, function(){
            $(".hoverMenu").stop().animate({
                top: '-247',
                opacity: '0'
            }, 500);
        });
```

When you hover over the second menu item, the div with a class of hoverMenu animates down, and increases its opacity until its fully visible. The problem I am having is after the hoverMenu animates down, I want to be able to hover over the individual links within the hoverMenu. Because I am hovering off the menuNav (the hovermenu is quote big with a series of list items and anchors), the hoverMenu animates back up. I want to modify my jquery so when you hover over .hovermenu, it will not animate back off.

If that doesnt make sense, I will throw together a jsfiddle, but I feel like this is a fairly common problem. TO summarize, because I am hovering off the #menu-nav, the hoverMenu animates up; however I would like the hoverMenu to stay put until I hover off BOTH the hoverMenu and #menu-nav

Comment: There's a very similar question to this floating around, I posted an answer to it I believe, but I can't seem to find it now. I believe the gist of what you need to do is to unbind when you hover over the main `li` so that you can freely move around the drop-down.

Comment: Your problem seems rather similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877178/jquery-menu-works-well-on-hover-but-sub-menu-disappears-on-click as they had their menu showing but just disappearing on click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make hoverMenu a child of #menu-nav, and when you hover on it, it still counts as hovering over #menu-dav since it's a child.

Comment: the #menu-nav is dynamically generated by wordpress, so I cannot add it as a child, can I?

Comment: @JCASE11 Why can't you? Just have it generated at the right spot in the HTML. If nothing else you can use jQuery to move it.

Answer (score 0):

It is a fairly common problem and the approach I prefer is to simply add the sub-menu as a child of the main item.  In this way, the sub-menu is part of the item with the `hover` on it, so your mouse entering the sub-menu will not trigger the leave event.  This generally works since the sub-menu is usually absolutely positioned anyway, so it's trivial to add it as a child of the other item.